# Data doesn't update

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update the column `number`
But I can't get it to work properly.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

        ob_start();
        require_once('includes/db.php');
        require_once('includes/init.php');
        if(!($user->LoggedIn())){
            header('location: login.php');
            die();
        }
        if(!($user->isAdmin($odb))){
            header('location: index.php');
        }
        if(!($user->notBanned($odb))){
            header('location: logout.php');
            die();
        }
        if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
            header('location: index.php');
        }
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $SQLGetInfo = $odb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `keys` WHERE `id` = :id LIMIT 1");
        $SQLGetInfo->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']));
?>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['updateBtn'])){
        $update = false;
        if($username != $_POST['keyname']){

           if(ctype_alnum($_POST['keyname']) && strlen($_POST['keyname']) >= 4 && strlen($_POST['keyname']) <= 35){
             $SQL = $odb->prepare("UPDATE  `u138461750_log`.`keys` SET  `number` =  ':keyname' WHERE `keys`.`number` = :number");
             $SQL->execute(array(':keyname' => $_POST['keyname'], ':keyname' => $id));
             $update = true;
             $username = $_POST['keyname'];
            } 
           else {
             echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><p>Key has to be alphanumeric 4 > 35</p></div>';
           }
      }
?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Key</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keyname" placeholder="keyname" value="<?php echo $id;?>"/>
        <button type="submit" name="updateBtn" class="btn btn-default">Update</button>
    </div>
```

[image: Picture from database]

Comment: What is `$odb`? A `PDO` connection?

Comment: Yes it is, It works fine on everything else. So the problem isn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line

```
$SQL = $odb->prepare("UPDATE  `u138461750_log`.`keys` SET  `number` =  ':keyname' WHERE `keys`.`number` = :number");
```

should read:

```
$SQL = $odb->prepare("UPDATE  `u138461750_log`.`keys` SET  `number` =  :keyname WHERE `keys`.`number` = :number");
```

Otherwise instead of using a named placeholder you are setting the number to the literal string ":keyname".

Comment: Thank you. Currently i'm struggeling with this one a little, Im fairly new to mysql. $SQL->execute(array(':keyname' => $_POST['keyname'], ':keyname' => $id));

Comment: I'm not at all clear what the code is supposed to do but you shouldn't be setting the same parameter to two different values. Should your second `:keyname` read `:number`?

Comment: Could you show me how to do it? I've been running around this issue for days. I just can't seem to fix it.

Comment: Sounds like you might have fixed it. But I'm afraid it isn't clear enough what you're trying to do or what the specific problem is for me to help much further.